# Tool to find out why and what code links to a specific dll

Tags: linker, dependencies, cmake

I have a big 64bit project that I have to deploy. Using the dependency walker on the final executable I found out that it links to cuda dll (`cudart64_50_35.dll`), and it shouldn't. So I'd like to find out the library or code that provokes this linking. Do you know tools to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml) (paid) or [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) (free).

Don't forget to load symbols.

Comment: Oh, it doesn't handle 64-bit executables :S Added to the question

Comment: [Immunity Debugger](http://www.immunitysec.com/products-immdbg.shtml) is a python based debugger, and it works on 64 bit as well

Comment: :D thanks Tzach, you're like a swiss knife :) Mmh... however I get the same error message as the OllyDbg when loading the binary. It tells me the binary does not look as 32-bit, and effectevly fails immediatelly afterwards.

Comment: no problem :) you can use windbg, it's a little harder to use but you can try setting breakpoints on every function of `cudart64_50_35.dll`, run the program and hope it will be invoked.